# Can a multivariate function be represented as finite combination of one-variable functions?

Tags: functions

Suppose we have a function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, which is analytic almost everywhere. Can one say that there exists a finite sequence of operations, which will evaluate $f$ for any argument, if the operations are limited to:

- arbitrary (piecewise-) analytic single-variable functions $g_i\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$
- arithmetic

? How can this be (dis)proved?

Comment: I suppose you have considered the case $n=2$ with $f$ multiplication; which solution would you propose? You can do some things with logarithms, but you must also cater for multiplication by$~0$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen you're right. Additions are too restrictive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question (especially version 1) appears to be almost exactly what is proved in [Kolmogorov–Arnold representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold_representation_theorem) if $f$ is continuous. The theorem states that any continuous function of any number of variables can be represented as a superposition of finite number of one-dimensional functions and additions, i.e. exist such finite families of functions $\Phi_q$ and $\psi_{q,p}$ that

$$f(x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_{q=0}^{2n}\Phi_q\left(\sum_{p=1}^n\psi_{q,p}(x_p)\right).$$